# using cppcheck with an explicit set of macro combinations

Tags: static-analysis, cppcheck

`cppcheck` produces a set of combinations of all macros that affect conditional compilation of all headers or sources by default, then filters them down to a set of some 12 combinations unless `--force` is used.

I have a large codebase with a lot of portability macros. I'm only interested in targeting a relatively small subset of these for what I'm testing, so I've used `--config-exclude=include/port/` to filter out all the port headers in my project.

The trouble is that cppcheck then appears to test no combinations at all - to the point where it fails to complain of obviously bogus code like

```
    int *foo = NULL;

    *foo = 1;
```

In any case, I'd actually like to test *some* combinations of macros, just not the whole unmanageable list.

Is there any sane way to get `cppcheck` to accept a list of macros to try combinations of? Or am I going to be stuck with generating explicit -U and -D lists to pass to it in multiple invocations myself?

I've noticed that it likes to try things like running with `-DMSC_VER` and without it. If I explicitly set `-DMSC_VER` then it finds a planted issue that's *outside* any `#ifdef MSC_VER` guard; but if I set `-UMSC_VER` then it fails to find the issue and appears to test zero combinations.

It's as if an explicit `-Umacro` doesn't execute the same path as the path cppcheck takes if it's allowed to try both the defined and not-defined paths itself...